# QGIS 3.0 Field calculator - Call second layer in Intersect

Tags: field-calculator, intersection, qgis-3

I am trying to use the 'intersects' function within an 'if' condition. If a polygon in Layer A intersects a polygon in layer B, then the cell should display 'YES', otherwise 'No'.

However, I don't know how to properly call the Layer B in the field calculator. The expression I am working on looks like this :

`if(intersects( $geometry,geometry('LayerB') ),"YES","NO")`

Does anyone know how to put it correctly?

Comment: For one thing, the `intersects` command will return a true/false response without the if statement, so you can drop that part. More importantly, though, the `intersects` command requires that you have a specific geometry to test against. If you just want to check if it intersects ANY polygon in the second layer, you're going to need to do something a little more involved. Suggestion: use the *Select by location* tool to specify cross-layer intersections, then just create the new field and update selected features only.

Comment: I thought about 'Select By Location', but I wanted to use the graphical modeler and didn't know if it would work. Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax for your expression is

```
    IF (aggregate(layer:='Layer B', aggregate:= 'count', expression:= $id, 
       filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent))), 
       concat ('yes'), concat('no'))
```

This is the result: 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using [refFunctions](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/) :

```
if( intersecting_geom_count('LayerB') > 0, 'YES', 'NO' )
```

(Sorry it is not QGIS3.0 specific, not using `intersects` function...)